# How can I get a specific part of data out of a SOAP array response?

Tags: ruby, soap, soap-client

I just started using ruby and have spent all morning beating my head against this one.  I am getting a response from a SOAP server as an array (shown below), and using this code to try and get the callID for the active call(78523):

```
activecall = driver.GetActiveCalls("clientHandle"=>handle,
            "lineID"=>line["OpenLineResult"].lineID,
            "getCallParties"=>1,
            "getCallProperties"=>1)

print "  call ID = ", activecall["GetActiveCallsResult"].callID,
  "\n  Line Type = ", activecall["GetActiveCallsResult"].calledID, "\n\n"
```

I get the error:

```
 undefined method `callID' for #<SOAP::Mapping::Object:0x..fdb79d636> (NoMethodError)
```

Any Idea what I am doing wrong, and how I can extract this data?

```
<SOAP::Mapping::Object:0x..fdb7ab5e2 {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}GetActiveCallsResult=#
<SOAP::Mapping::Object:0x..fdb7ab4b6 {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}ShoreTelCallStateInfo=[#
    <SOAP::Mapping::Object:0x..fdb7ab3b2 {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}callInfo=#
        <SOAP::Mapping::Object:0x..fdb7ab25e {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}lineID="20659" 
            {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}callID="71495" 
            {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}isExternal="true" 
            {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}isInbound="false" 
            {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}callReason="None" 
            {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}connectedID="9+18012624550" 
            {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}callerID="1955" 
            {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}callerIDName="Joel Lewis" 
            {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}calledID="9+18012624550" 
            {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}callParties=#
    <SOAP::Mapping::Object:0x..fdb7a8b3a {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}CallPartyInfo=#
        <SOAP::Mapping::Object:0x..fdb7a89fa {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}partyNumber="1" 
            {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}partyType="Trunk" 
            {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}partyCCOID="1073742591" 
            {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}trunkInfo=#
    <SOAP::Mapping::Object:0x..fdb7a7cb2 {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}trunkType="DigitalPRI" 
        {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}trunkSwitch="5" 
        {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}trunkPort="21" 
        {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}trunkPortName=" E-Link  (21)">>> 
        {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}callUniqueID="2572420445" 
        {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}callGUID="{00030000-D992-537E-3FD3-0010492377D9}"> 
        {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}callState="OnHold" 
        {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}callStateDetail="Active">, 
    #<SOAP::Mapping::Object:0x..fdb7a4d1e {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}callInfo=#
    <SOAP::Mapping::Object:0x..fdb7a4bca {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}lineID="20659" 
    {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}callID="78523" 
    {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}isExternal="true" 
    {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}isInbound="false" 
    {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}callReason="None" 
    {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}connectedID="9+13852045017" 
    {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}callerID="1955" 
    {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}callerIDName="Joel Lewis" 
    {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}calledID="9+13852045017" 
    {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}callParties=#
    <SOAP::Mapping::Object:0x..fdb7a256e {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}CallPartyInfo=#
    <SOAP::Mapping::Object:0x..fdb7a2460 {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}partyNumber="1" 
    {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}partyType="Trunk" 
    {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}partyCCOID="1073742590" 
    {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}trunkInfo=#<SOAP::Mapping::Object:0x..fdb7a172c 
    {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}trunkType="DigitalPRI" 
    {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}trunkSwitch="5" 
    {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}trunkPort="20" {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}trunkPortName=" E-Link  (20)">>>
    {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}callUniqueID="2320005488" 
    {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}callGUID="{00030000-D995-537E-3FD3-0010492377D9}"> 
    {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}callState="Connected" 
    {http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web}callStateDetail="Active">]>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing with SOAP from ruby side it would recomment to use http://savonrb.com/version2. But anyway have you tried something like

```
activecall["GetActiveCallsResult"]["ShoreTelCallStateInfo"]
```

I think these MappingObjects provides access to the chield nodes like you would access an hash with a key, in this case the qualified name of the xml mode see http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/soap/rdoc/SOAP/Mapping/Object.html.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, 
activecall["GetActiveCallsResult"]["ShoreTelCallStateInfo"]["callInfo"].callID is getting me what I need when I have only one record.  But when there are two records I get the following error: can't convert String into Integer (TypeError).  Any Idea how to get multiple variables?